# Remote workers on multiple servers with python-rq (redis)

Tags: redis, python-rq

I am using `redis` and `python-rq` to manage a data processing task. I wish to distribute the data processing across multiple servers (each server would manage several rq workers) but I would like to keep a unique queue on a master server.

Is there a way to achieve this using `python-rq` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be easy enough. There are two steps:

1) Configure `Redis` on the master machine so that it is open to external communications by the remote "agent" server. This is done by editing the `bind` information as explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416007/what-does-the-bind-parameter-do-in-redis). Make sure to set a password if setting the bind value to `0.0.0.0` as this will open the Redis connection to anyone.

2) Start the worker on the remote "agent" server using the `url` parameter:

```
rq worker --url redis://:[your_master_redis_password]@[your_master_server_IP_address]
```

On the master server, you can check that the connection was properly made by typing:

```
rq info --url redis://:[your_master_redis_password]@localhost
```

If you enabled the localhost binding, this should display all the workers available to `Redis` from your "master" including the new worker you created on your remote server.